# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in arguments array

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, indexoutofboundsexception

Input file: file1.cmd

```
A = 7
B = 8
```

CODE

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Commander
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String,Integer> expression = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Variable, assignmentOperator;
        int Value, i = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            args[i] = sc.nextLine();
            args[i + 1] = sc.nextLine();
            args[i + 2] = sc.nextLine();

            expression.put(args[i],Integer.parseInt(args[i + 2]));

            for(String key: expression.keySet())
                System.out.println(key + " - " + expression.get(key));

            if(!sc.hasNextLine()) break;

            ++i;

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Commander.main(Commander.java:17)
```

I am having difficulty in resolving this error, any help is appreciated. According to my cmd file, A is args[0], = is args[1] and 7 is args[2], then a new line is started in which B is the new value of args[0] ? I am confused.

Comment: Why are you assigning values to args? Thats probably a bad idea.

Comment: You're using main's args array, which if you're just running in your compiler likely has no arguments and a length of 0. You need to declare your own array. After that, you'll probably get a few more errors from the sc.nextLine() not being checked.

Comment: How do I end the loop if there are no more command line arguments to process ? I understand it doesn't make sense to use scanner when reading in command line arguments. I want to read in one command line at a time, process it then read the next command line argument

Comment: First of all let's get your terminology straight.  If you're in a `Command Prompt` window (on Windows) and you type in something like `java MainProgram 1 15 3`, then what you typed in is the _command line_ and the arguments `1`, `15`, and `3` are _command-line arguments_.  Stuff you read in from a file is not "command line arguments".

Comment: Do you know what a command line argument is? You don't read that manually, it will be provided in the `args` array automatically. If you run the command `java -jar Commander.jar A = 7 B = 8` that array would be `[A, =, 7, B, =, 8]`.

Comment: I understand, but what I want to do is read in the command line argument A = 7, process some action, then read in the next 3 command line arguments until i reach the end of the cmd file. How do I continue processing 3 arguments at a time until end of file is reached ? I guess that would've been a more appropriate question.

Comment: `nextLine()` reads an entire line.  If you want to read `"A"`, `"="`, and `"7"` separately, you can't use `nextLine()` because that will return `"A = 7"` as one string.  Please read the [`Scanner` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  And please stop calling them "command line arguments".  You will only keep confusing yourself and everybody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your current error is because you are trying to assign values to the args array, which is empty and shouldn't be used in your case.**

When you run your Java program from the command promp (windows) the extra strings (separated by spaces) behind the program name will be in your list of arguments.

`java RunningThisProgram 7 8`

Your program could then be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(args[0]); //prints "7"
    System.out.println(args[1]); //prints "8"
}
```

This is fine if you know your arguments before you even start the program. But lets say you want to have the program running and THEN pass something into the console. Or, **read them from a file.**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //args is an empty array, pretend it doesn't even exist
    String[] inputLines = new String[10];//This array has enough room for 10 entries
    //Now you have an empty array you can read lines in and assign values to
}
```

Note that we set a specified length of 10. Arrays cannot be dynamically resized by themselves. The easiest way to read in any number of items like that is by using a `List` of some type, most likely `ArrayList`. You could also have the first string you read in be how many entries the user wishes to add.

---

After reading your comment, I will add that the thing you think you are having trouble with is the condition inside of your `while` loop. You should change the condition, (the `true`)

`while (true)` will continue running forever by itself. You seem to be calling `break` from inside your while loop, which could work, but isn't a good way to do it.

You will want

```
while (yourCondition)
{
    //doStuff
}
```

`yourCondition` could be any boolean. You could check if they enter the line "QUIT", or if you are at the end of the file, just for example.

Answer (score 2):

you're reusing the args array from the main() method, if you didn't pass any command line arguments in, it will be length zero. you REALLY want to use a seperate array, or a list if you dont know how many lines you will read in.